# Allow popper to go outside the boundaries of the container

Tags: popper.js

I am using popper.js on the items in a custom-built dropdown menu (it's not a `<select>`). The site uses Bootstrap 4.

My poppers look like this, **but I want it to overflow outside of the scrolling container:**

[image]

I want the poppers to appear on the right-hand side of the elements in the scrolling container, but they are forced to stay inside of it. The scrolling container is a `<div>`.

**Why don't these settings allow the poppers to overflow?**:

```
const indivOptionPopOverSettings = {
        placement: 'left',
        container: 'body',
        trigger: 'hover',
        html: true,
        modifiers: {
            preventOverflow: {
                // tried these individually and in various combinations:
                enabled: false,
                boundariesElement: 'window',
                escapeWithReference: true
            }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

The "container: 'body'" attribute allows the pop-over box to be put directly under the body tag and not the div tag hence resolving the issue.

Answer (score -3):

The problem went away after I closed my browser entirely and restarted the application. I'm not sure what the root problem was.

Comment: @josh_withee, how did you solve this?

Comment: @Josh Withee I wonder the same. I have the same issue and not much info

Comment: I'm with you people! 
OP @Josh Withee please elaborate on how you were able to fix this.

Comment: I wish I had more info to share but that is all I did and the problem stopped happening.

Comment: Has anyone figured this out, because I added the `container: 'body'` and it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Seems like [this](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/constructors/#strategy) this did the trick for me and I did not need the `container: 'body'` either.